# Angular js order by date dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: angularjs

I want to order date. But doesn't work correctly. Date format is dd-mm-yyyy. Just order dd format doesn't check mm and yyyy. How can I solve?

**JS**

```
    $scope.sortOptions = [                       
        {
            name:'Date desc',
            sortCategory:'-anndate'
        },            
        {
            name:'Date asc',
            sortCategory:'anndate'
        }       
    ];
```

**HTML**

```
    <select ng-model="selectedSortType" class="custom-select">
        <option value="" selected="">Select type</option>
        <option value='{{opt.sortCategory}}' ng-repeat="opt in sortOptions track by $index">{{opt.name}}</option>
    </select>  
   <div ng-repeat="i in res| orderBy:selectedSortType">
       <div>{{i.anndate}}</div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

Since the date in `res` object is in string format the filter is applying on dd value.

For entire `date` filter you need to convert the `anndate` to `Date()` object
Place the following code in the line below assigning `res` value in controller

```
angular.forEach($scope.res,function(item){ item.anndate = new Date(item.anndate); });
```

Then in html replace with below line

```
 <select ng-model="selectedSortType" class="custom-select">
        <option value="" selected="">Select type</option>
        <option value='{{opt.sortCategory}}' ng-repeat="opt in sortOptions track by $index">{{opt.name}}</option>
    </select>  
   <div ng-repeat="i in res| orderBy:selectedSortType">
       <div>{{i.anndate| date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Your solution is correct  thanks. But when I write console log date some date is returning invalid date. item.anndate 14-05-2018, new Date(item.anndate) Invalid Date

Comment: Also print result is "2018-09-04T21:00:00.000Z" I think date filter didn't work

Comment: you need to apply filter for the date

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('appController', appController);

appController.$inject = ['$scope', '$window'];

function appController($scope, $window) {

    $scope.title = "date sorting example";

    $scope.sortOptions = [{
            name: 'Date desc',
            sortCategory: '2018-07-15 '
        },
        {
            name: 'Date desc',
            sortCategory: '2018-07-12 '
        },
        {
            name: 'Date asc',
            sortCategory: '2018-07-13'
        }
    ];
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">



<p>Ascending Order</p>
<div ng-repeat="i in sortOptions | orderBy:'sortCategory'">
  <p>{{i.sortCategory}}</p>
</div>
 <select ng-model="selectedSortType" class="custom-select">
        <option value="" selected="">Select type</option>
        <option value='{{opt.sortCategory}}' ng-repeat="opt in sortOptions | orderBy:'sortCategory'">{{opt.sortCategory}}</option>
    </select>  
<p>Descending Order</p>
<div ng-repeat="i in sortOptions | orderBy:'-sortCategory'">
  <p>{{i.sortCategory}}</p>
</div>
 <select ng-model="selectedSortType" class="custom-select">
        <option value="" selected="">Select type</option>
        <option value='{{opt.sortCategory}}' ng-repeat="opt in sortOptions | orderBy:'-sortCategory'">{{opt.sortCategory}}</option>
    </select>  
</div>
```